# Calculation within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Need help here to complete a project.

In my web application, there is a view that users assigned marks for tasks that are listed from 1 to 5.

This is the calculation I have done in the Controller.

```
public ActionResult UpdateHod(MainDetailsVM mainDetailsVM) {
   
   //Kpi Calculation
   const int kpMarks = 65;
   int kpiCounts = mainDetailsVM.KPIMarksVMList.Count();
   decimal KpMarksPerQuiz = (kpMarks / kpiCounts) / 5;
   decimal kpiMarks = 0;
   //Performance Calculation
   decimal comtoMarks = 0;
 
   //SelfCompetence Calculation
   const int sMarks = 10;
   int sCounts = mainDetailsVM.SelfImprovementMainVMList.Count();
   decimal sMarksPerQuiz = (sMarks / sCounts) / 5;
   decimal sMarksTotal = 0;
 
   foreach(var item in mainDetailsVM.KPIMarksVMList) {
     decimal k = KpMarksPerQuiz * item.SupervisorMarks;
     kpiMarks += k;
     
   }
 
   foreach(var item in mainDetailsVM.PerformanceMainList) {
     performance.SupervisorMarks = item.SupervisorMarks;
     comtoMarks += item.SupervisorMarks;
   }
 
   foreach(var item in mainDetailsVM.SelfImprovementMainVMList) {
     decimal s = sMarksPerQuiz * item.SupervisorMarks;
     sMarksTotal += s;
   }
 
   main.KPMarks = kpiMarks;
   decimal cMark = comtoMarks / 4;
   main.CompetenciesMarks = cMark;
   main.ImprovMarks = sMarksTotal;
   decimal totMarks = kpiMarks + cMark + sMarksTotal;
 
   if (totMarks >= 80) {
     main.MarksGrade = "A";
 
   } else if (totMarks >= 60 && totMarks <= 79) {
     main.MarksGrade = "B";
   } else if (totMarks >= 40 && totMarks <= 59) {
     main.MarksGrade = "C";
   } else if (totMarks >= 20 && totMarks <= 39) {
     main.MarksGrade = "D";
   } else {
     main.MarksGrade = "E";
   }
 
 }
```

When the User clicks on the submit button I do this calculation and save it in the database.

I need to do this calculation and show the data before saving it to the database.

So there are 3 lists of tasks and the count of the tasks is calculated from the Length of the list.

Can It possible to pass the model data using Ajax call and do the calculations and pass it to the view?

This is the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Performance", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken() {
<form id="PerformanceForm"> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.First().EmpId)
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- Default box -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div id="loading" class="overlay" style="display:none"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i></div>
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title text-center">Performance Evaluation Form</h3>
                            <div class="card-tools">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" title="Collapse"> <i class="fas fa-minus"></i> </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <section>
                                <h3>Key Performance Indicators</h3>
                                <div id="KPIS"> </div>
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> </th>
                                            <th> </th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody> @for (int i = 0; i
                                        < Model.First().KPIMarksVMList.Count(); i++) { <tr>
                                            <td style="display:none;"> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].KPIId) </td>
                                            <td width="60%"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].KPIName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="radio"> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "1") 1 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "2") 2 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "3") 3 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "4") 4 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "5", new { @checked = "Checked" }) 5 </div>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr> } </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </section>
                            <section>
                                <div id="KPIS"> </div>
                                <br />
                                <h3>Competency</h3>
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> </th>
                                            <th> </th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody> @for (int i = 0; i
                                        < Model.First().PerformanceMainList.Count(); i++) { <tr>
                                            <td style="display:none;"> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId) </td>
                                            <td width="20%"> @if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 1) 
                                            {
                                                <p>Technical Application</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if 
                                                (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 3)
                                                {
                                                <p>Work Organization</p>
                                                }
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 5) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Administration Of Work</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 7) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Creativity</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 9) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Communication Skills</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 11) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Work Performance</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 13) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Reliability and Punctuality</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 15) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Leadership</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 17) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Problem Solving & Decision Making</p> 
                                                } 
                                                else if (Model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceMainId == 19) 
                                                {
                                                <p>Target Achievement</p>
                                                } 
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="50%"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].PerformanceKPIName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) </td>
                                                <td width="30%">
                                                <div class="radio"> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].EmpMarks, "1") 1 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].EmpMarks, "2") 2 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].EmpMarks, "3") 3 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].EmpMarks, "4") 4 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().PerformanceMainList[i].EmpMarks, "5", new { @checked = "Checked" }) 5 </div>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr> 
                                                } 
                                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </section>
                            <section>
                                <br />
                                <h3>Continuous Self-Improvement & Cross Functional Activities</h3>
                                <div id="SelfImpro"> </div>
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> </th>
                                            <th> </th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody> 
                                    @for (int i = 0; i <Model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList.Count(); i++) 
                                    { 
                                    <tr>
                                    <td style="display:none;"> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].SelfImpId) </td>
                                    <td width="60%"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].SelfImName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <div class="radio"> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].EmpMarks, "0") 0 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].EmpMarks, "1") 1 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].EmpMarks, "2") 2 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].EmpMarks, "3") 3 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].EmpMarks, "4") 4 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().SelfImprovementMainVMList[i].EmpMarks, "5", new { @checked = "Checked" }) 5 </div>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr> 
                                    } 
                                    </tbody>
                                <br />
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form> }
<div class="card-footer">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Request" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-show" /> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" value="Check MarksRequest" class="btn btn-success" id="btnsubmit" /> </div>
    </div>
</div> 
}
```

Or can we do the same calculation within the javascript ? If yes, any help for that. Thanks

This is the java script I tried to submit the model to JasonResult. Not worked.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnsubmit").click(function (e) {
            //Serialize the form datas.
            var valdata = $("#PerformanceForm").serialize();
            //to get alert popup
            alert(valdata);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Performance/CalculateAmount",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                data: { valdata },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success == true) {

                        alert("Hey");

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Everything you use to perform the calculation comes from the page, so why wouldn't you be able to do this in javascript. Make an attempt and come back if you struggle.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Hi I updated the question with the Javascript I tried. I tried sending the model to JasoResult. But no data passing to it.

Comment: Have you considered replicating your calculation code in JavaScript? By the way, in your AJAX request, combining dataType as "JSON" and contentType as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" seems very confusing, since they are different formats.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I got the code from the forum. I did changes to the code and now it passing the model to the JasonResult through the Ajax call. But the issue is user selected values from the radio button are not passing. The reason Is I only pass the model. So is there any way of showing me how to get the selected values to the Javascript from ``Model.First().KPIMarksVMList.Count()``